# relation between moments of discrete random variable and CDF

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider a discrete positive random variable, say X. [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684279/is-there-a-convenient-formula-for-variance-of-discrete-random-variable-in-terms) nicely shows that

\begin{equation}
E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-F(k))
\end{equation}

Moreover,

\begin{equation}
E[X^2] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (2k+1)(1-F(k))
\end{equation}

I am puzzled on how to obtain the factor "(2k+1)" in above expression. It would be nice, when there were a relation between F(X) and X for higher order moments.

Comment: Doesn't the answer to the question in your link explain where the $2k+1$ comes from?

Comment: Please, what link are you referring to? The only link, namely http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90591/25936 , points to an application using above expression.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/684348/43949) in your link gives you the explanation already...

If $G$ is the CDF of $X^2$ then the first formula yields
$$E[X^2] = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (1 - G(k))
= (1-G(0)) + (1-G(1)) + (1-G(2)) + \cdots.$$
Since $X$ takes integer values, we have $X^2 \in \{0^2, 1^2, 2^2, 3^3, \ldots\}$, so $G(1)=G(2)=G(3)=F(1)$ and $G(4) = G(5) = G(6) = G(7) = G(8) = F(2)$ and so on.
Writing all the $G$ terms (in the above sum) in terms of $F$ and collecting like terms yields the $(2k+1)(1-F(k))$ expression.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the hint. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/intuition-behind-using-complementary-cdf-to-compute-expectation-for-nonnegative) post, it is now clear that one has to rewrite
\begin{equation}
E[X^2] = \sum_k k^2 P(X=k)
\end{equation}
as
\begin{equation}
E[X^2] = \sum_k H(k) P(X>k)
\end{equation}
where H(k) is the unknown term. When we write the elements of the sum as matrix, then the sum in the first equation corresponds to column-wise summation, while that of the second equation corresponds to row-wise summation.
 Setting
\begin{equation}
\sum_k H(k) P(X>k) = \sum_k k^2 P(X=k)
\end{equation}
one can easily get the term H(k).